# How to get box-shadow over another box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a box shadow but as soon as another box hits it the box shadow is invisible. I'd like to have the box-shadow go over the other box.

Here an example of what is going wrong. As you can see there is a shadow where there is not box.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lawwf/4hck7/)

**HTML**

```
<header>
</header>

<div id="content">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
height: 100px;
background: black;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
}

#content {
width: 350px;
height: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #CCCCCC;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML elements are positioned statically by default in document normal flow.

You have to [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) the header as `relative` and add a higher `z-index` (if needed) to bring that element at the top of the others without changing layout, as follows:

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10; /* optional */
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/4hck7/3/)**.

Answer (score 1):

try `position:absolute or relative` for the header

```
header {
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}

#content {
    width: 350px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #CCCCCC;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hck7/4/)